# RecyclerView pierde datos al hacer scroll

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Tengo un `recyclerview` que es manejado por este `adapter` al momento de hacer `scroll` en los elemento el mapa pierde la información (ubicación que tiene) entiendo que es por que el `recyclerview` ahorra memoria mostrando solo unos elementos a diferencia de un `listview`. Que puedo hacer para no perder la información

```
package mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.ui;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.R;



public class Multas_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Multas_Adapter.ViewHolderDatos>
{

    ArrayList<recycle_Multas_Adapter> listas_Informacion;
    private Context context;

    public Multas_Adapter(ArrayList<recycle_Multas_Adapter> listas_Informacion) {
        this.listas_Informacion = listas_Informacion;
        this.context= context;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.multas_generadas,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int i) {
        holder.nombre.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getNombre());
        holder.direccion.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDireccion());
        holder.multa.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDato());
        holder.lt=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt();
        holder.lg=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg();
        holder.Lugar=new LatLng(listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt(),listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
        holder.neto=listas_Informacion.get(i).getMonto();
        holder.monto.setText("$"+holder.neto);
        holder.folio.setText(""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getFolio());
        holder.url=holder.url+"&markers=color:green%7Clabel:%7C"+holder.lt+","+holder.lg+"&key=Mikey";
        Picasso.with(context).load(holder.url).into(holder.map);
        // LatLng Lugar = new LatLng(listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt(),listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
       // holder.ubi.setText(""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt()+""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listas_Informacion.size();
    }


    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolderDatos holder)
    {

    }

    public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView multa,direccion,nombre,monto,folio;
        double lt,lg, neto;
        LatLng Lugar;
        ImageView map;
        String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=20&size=1000x400&scale=10";
        public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            monto=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Monto);
            map=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map_card);
            multa=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.multa);
            direccion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
            nombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            folio=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.folio);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta deshabilitando la propiedad isRecyclable:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderDatos holder, int i) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false); // Deshabilitada
    holder.nombre.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getNombre());
    holder.direccion.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDireccion());
    holder.multa.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDato());
    holder.lt=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt();
    holder.lg=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg();
    holder.Lugar=new LatLng(listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt(),listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
    holder.neto=listas_Informacion.get(i).getMonto();
    holder.monto.setText("$"+holder.neto);
    holder.folio.setText(""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getFolio());
    holder.url=holder.url+"&markers=color:green%7Clabel:%7C"+holder.lt+","+holder.lg+"&key=Mikey";
    Picasso.with(context).load(holder.url).into(holder.map);
    // LatLng Lugar = new LatLng(listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt(),listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
    // holder.ubi.setText(""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt()+""+listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());
}
```

Es díficl probar el código debido a la variedad de recursos que manejas, ojalá te sirva de algo.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, eso me sirvio <3